# Revalidate Credentials on WCF UserNamePasswordValidator on each call

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I am using a custom Username/Password Validator on WCF over NetTcp, to authenticate clients connecting to my WCF Service. What I noticed, is that once a client gets authenticated, never gets validated again, meaning that if I want to revoke access from a client, I would need to manually force him to disconnect.

My serviceHost configuration looks like this:

```
_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(credentialsBehavior);
_serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
_serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = _userValidator;
_serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(AppSettingsManager.I.CertificateStoreLocation, AppSettingsManager.I.CertificateStoreName, AppSettingsManager.I.CertificateFindBy, AppSettingsManager.I.CertificateFindValue);
```

and my clients connect using ChannelFactory:

```
var client = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>(new InstanceContext(this), binding, endpointAddress);
client.Credentials.UserName.UserName = ConnectionProperties.Authentication.Credentials.Username;
client.Credentials.UserName.Password = ConnectionProperties.Authentication.Credentials.Password;
client.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = AppSettingsManager.I.CertificateValidationMode;

client.CreateChannel();
```

Is there a way to have the client credentials validated on every call, or periodically?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, after invocation, the server will automatically close the connection, it depends on the following parameter of the binding.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
Of course, we can also close it manually on the client.

```
client.Close()
```

In addition, I could not get your point. the session is continual, and you have set up the credential in the code snippets before calling the service. What do you mean that Never Gets Validate again?
In my opinion, if you want to revoke access from a client, you could change the validation logic on the server side.

Comment: I get that, one case I'm worried about is the following: A client connects to the server using valid credentials. Then an Administrator resets their credentials. As long as the client doesn't close the connection, they will never get de-authenticated. Of course that's something I could handle manually, outside the validator, but I want to explore if there's a way WCF can do that for me. Closing the connection is not an option, as I use client registration with callbacks to talk back to the clients from the server.

Comment: Or can we control the validity of this connection through the timeout parameter? 
Like Receivetimeout. this is only my thought.